# Ввод даты в maskedit

Tags: delphi

Есть maskedit с маской `!99/99/0000;1;_`. Проблема такого характера... если в него вводить, к примеру, 12.11.2012, то все нормально, а если ввести что-то типа `99.99.9999`, то тогда происходит ошибка конвертации, ведь такой даты и месяца быть не может и конвертация дает ошибку. Подскажите, как сделать проверку ввода в maskedit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/88254/%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-edit?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=88281#88281), в вашем же топике, на эту же тему.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего на if.
Синтаксис Delphi не знаю, но выглядеть пудет примерно так:

```
if переменная < допустимое значения then
writeln('Ошибка!');
else:endif
```