# Ввод определенных символов в edit

Tags: delphi

Есть maskedit, надо чтобы при вводе в первую позицию вводилось только 1 или 2 или 3, во вторую позицию - цифры от 0 до 9... как-то так... как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

берем маску, например: 99;1;_

пишем обработчик :

```
procedure TForm1.MaskEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  stroka: string;
begin
  if (MaskEdit1.Text[1] <> '1') and (MaskEdit1.Text[1] <> '2') and  (MaskEdit1.Text[1] <> '3') then
    begin
      stroka:= MaskEdit1.Text;
      stroka[1]:= '_';
      MaskEdit1.Text:= stroka;
    end;
end;
```

или такой обработчик:

```
procedure TForm1.MaskEdit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if MaskEdit1.SelStart = 0 then
    if not (key in ['1'..'3']) then
      key:= '_';
end;
```